# Large prediction results unless using repartition(1) in databricks with lgbm model in mmlspark

Tags: pyspark, bigdata, databricks, lightgbm

I'm using `mmlspark lgbm` model for regression problem and faced strange thing. If using all normal code as in the example, results will be terrible, because predictions are huge (around 10^37, while the target is in the range from 0 to 200).
Testing, I found that using `dataset.repartition(1).cache()` fixed this problem, but with one detail - modelling began to take longer (around 1h, while 20m earlier). This is logical since all the data (about 4m rows and 150 columns) is collected before learning in one partition.

I tried changing `lgbm` param useBarrierExecutionMode to True and different parallelism params, but this change doesn't affect the result.

Is there a way not to use such workaround with a repartition and still having normal results?

Code, used for training

```
repartitioned_data = data_train.repartition(1).cache() #  want to delete this line

  # Define model
  model = LightGBMRegressor(
      objective='regression',
      labelCol='label',
      featuresCol="features"
  )

  # Define grid params
  paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder() \
          .addGrid(model.numIterations, [100, 250])\
        .build()

  # Define cross validation for grid params
  evaluator = RegressionEvaluator(labelCol="label", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="mae")
  crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=model,
                      estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
                      evaluator=evaluator,   
                      numFolds=2)

  # Train model
  pipeline = crossval.fit(repartitioned_data)
```

- Databricks Runtime Version 6.4 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.5, Scala
  2.11)
- 3 worker nodes Standard_DS4_v2
- driver node Standard_DS4_v2
- mmlspark version mmlspark_2.11:1.0.0-rc3

Comment: Are you running ```pipeline = crossval.fit(data_train)``` or ```pipeline = crossval.fit(repartitioned_data )```?

Comment: @LuizViola, `crossval.fit(repartitioned_data )`. Made a mistake in the question